# "Is a field but is used like a type" error

Tags: c#, xna

So I have project in C# .NET with XNA. My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace Fireflies
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        Texture2D backgroundImage;
        Texture2D swietlik;

        float vSwietlikX, vSwietlikY;
        Rectangle recSwietlik;

        int n = 20;                                     // objects population
        int d = 50;                                     // dimension

        int io = 10;                                    // max light intensity

        double alfa = 0.5;                              // alfa value
        double betao = 0.2;                             // beta value
        double gamma = 1.0;                             // gamma value

        Random rnd = new Random();

        List<Swietlik> populacja = new List<Swietlik>();
        List<Swietlik> sasiad = new List<Swietlik>();

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            // Generate new population
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                populacja.Add(new Swietlik(rnd.Next(0, 800), rnd.Next(0, 600), rnd.Next(0, 10)));
            }

            base.Initialize();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            backgroundImage = Content.Load<Texture2D>("BG");
            swietlik = Content.Load<Texture2D>("swietlik");

            recSwietlik = new Rectangle(rnd.Next(10), rnd.Next(10), (swietlik.Width / 10) * 4, (swietlik.Height / 10) * 4);
            vSwietlikX = vSwietlikY = 1;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            recSwietlik.X += (int)(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds * vSwietlikX);
            recSwietlik.Y += (int)(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds * vSwietlikY);

            if (recSwietlik.X < 0 || recSwietlik.X + recSwietlik.Width > GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width)
            {
                vSwietlikX = -(vSwietlikX);
            }
            if (recSwietlik.Y < 0 || recSwietlik.Y + recSwietlik.Height > GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height)
            {
                vSwietlikY = -(vSwietlikY);
            }

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.AliceBlue);
            // Drawing objects
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            spriteBatch.Draw(backgroundImage, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea, Color.White);
            foreach(swietlik in populacja)
            {
             spriteBatch.Draw(swietlik, recSwietlik, Color.White);
            }
            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation: in the Initialize() section I want to generate objects from a class (where I randomly generate value of position x, position y and light intensity of each objects) and put them into `List<Swietlik> populacja`. Then in the Draw() method I want to draw. I used a `foreach` loop, but I don't know what I should put into `spriteBatch.Draw` line and why I have "is a field but is used like a type" error.

Comment: Do you even search your error message on Google?

Comment: Yes, and I found that I should put that into main(). But I haven't main, and I am not sure where i should write this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
foreach(swietlik in populacja)
```

try changing it to this:

```
foreach(Swietlik s in populacja)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(swietlik, recSwietlik, Color.White);
}
```

`swietlik` is a `Texture2D`,  not a `Swietlik`, which is what the `populacja` list is populated with. You can't iterate through a list using a `Texture2D` instance. (You need a `type` and `identifier` in a foreach loop. If your `Swietlik` class has a rectangle property, and you want to draw each `Swietlik` at it's rectangle, then you could do this:

```
foreach(Swietlik s in populacja)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(swietlik, s.rectangle, Color.White);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help, but actually I found solution myself. My loop looks like:

```
    for (int b = 0; b < swietliki.Count; b++)
    {
        swietliki[b].Draw(spriteBatch);
    }
    spriteBatch.End();
```

Anyway, thank you ;)